# Importing a file with functions - attempted relative import with no known parent package erorr

Tags: python, import

there is my project hierachy:

```
#__init__.py are empty files

folder
 |-- globalFunctions.py
 |-- __init__.py
 |-- monitor
     |-- file.py
     |-- __init__.py
```

I'm tring to import functions from globalFunctions.py, when I'm in the file.py file.
I have tried to import it with

```
from .. import globalFunctions
```

but I'm getting

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Do you know how to make it work?

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: From where do you import your main package "folder"?

Comment: Your code looks fine; I have just checked, and I can import your "folder" package (and modules like `folder.monitor` and `folder.monitor.file`) just fine, and access `folder.monitor.file.globalFunctions` without error. So there is some context that you've not yet mentioned (such as where you are doing the actual importing, see my previous comment).

Comment: Are you running `file.py` as a script, for example **python3 file3.py**?

Comment: @Booboo yes, I'm running it on windows with "python -u file.py" command

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: Inside the file.py im using the functions from globalFunctions.py in this way:

Comment: proxyList = globalFunctions.getProxies() etc

Comment: You need to run it as a module:  `python -m folder.monitor.file`

Comment: I have tried running it with command python -m monitor.file, when I was in the folder file but I still recived ` attempted relative import with no known parent package` error

Comment: Okay, finally I got it. Thank you for your help and for the link to the ' Relative imports for the billionth time' question!

Comment: Don't run modules as file. The `-m` flag may help, but run things *outside* the package. Just don't "run" packages and modules until you understand what you are doing.